# Функция sleep из класса Thread

Tags: c#

Как работает функциа `sleep` из класса `Thread`?

Answer (score 1):

Просто сообщает планировщику потоков, что вызвавший ее поток не нужно ставить в очередь на планирование указанное время.

`Sleep(0);` имеет немножко другой смысл - поток говорит планировщику, что он отработал, и ему не нужен его квант времени.

Как вообще это все работает. Планировщик потоков просыпается время от времени и останавливает текущий поток. Потом выбирает новый поток и запускает его (хотя правильнее говорить, что он ставит и снимает с паузы, если поток был запущен раньше).

Comment: Только планировщик не останавливает текущий поток, а перепланирует набор исполняемых потоков в соответствии с критериями диспетчирования (**реально одновременно** исполняемых потоков может быть несколько). 

Не следует забывать также, что ОС учитывает все потоки в системе (а не только потоки Вашей программы).

Answer (score 0):

1. `.sleep(3000)` - приостанавливает
       поток на заданное время (3 сек) в
       миллисекундах
2. `.wait()` - приостанавливает до
       разблокировании методов `notify()` или
       `notifyAll()`

Comment: Обратите внимание на метку `csharp`

Comment: Да, видел, разве это меняет смысл методов? Кроме их синтаксиса?

Comment: ну, быстрый гугл подсказывает, что методы wait/notify/notifyAll вообще находятся в .NET в другом классе и называются по-другому - так что C#-еры (кстати, вы так себя называете?) могут вас не понять.